# C++ Winsocks Attempting to connect to multiple servers

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm trying to build an application that I can use on a network. It's really just a test, but I'd love to get it working.

### Specification

Basically, a load of computers on the same network will run small "servers" (like, really small - maximum about 2 connections?). Then, a client (also on that network) can be run that will connect to as many as it can.

This would be easy to code if you knew the IP addresses of the computers in advance, but I'm trying to get it to find available computers itself - by scanning through the possible IP addresses (by taking the client's local network IP and iteratively changing the final few digits).

Finally, I need it to be able to do it fairly quickly - even with a mere 2 second timeout, that's 255 x 2 = 510 seconds. And that's just for the final part of the IP - ideally, this would run over the final 2 portions, a full 65025 attempts (though this would obviously take a lot longer!).

### Question

First off, is this possible? Can one "client" socket throw out connection attempts to multiple computers at a time? And if it can, how can it do so efficiently? I've thought of threads, but they're a real pain to synchronise and keep track of, and I've looked into the `select` function, but can't work out how to get it working in this scenario.

Any help or advice is really appreciated!

hnefatl

Comment: Are the client and the servers on the same network? Can't you use broadcasting to discover available servers?

Comment: Sorry, they are on the same network - I'll edit it to fix that :) Could you explain a bit more what you mean by broadcasting? I'm familiar with it from UDP of course, but I'm not sure how to use that in this situation?

Comment: Regarding broadcasting, the client broadcasts a "servers, tell me where you are" discover message that all servers listen for (beside the normal connections). When a server gets that message it replies to the sender with a "here I am" message. The client waits a second or two to get as many replies as possible before starting to connect to the replying servers.

Comment: I would just put the broadcast code in a loop sending a few packets to all IP addresses iteratively, correct? That makes a lot of sense, thank you! And it is possible for a single client socket to connect to multiple servers from the same port, right?

Comment: A single client socket can only connect to one server. You need a socket for each connection.

Comment: Sorry, yes - but can one socket handle all the broadcasting to all the servers before connecting to them with another socket?